# Player object automatically jumping when hitting start button

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I have a canvas that is initialized when I launch the game and inside it I have a menu with the play and quit button. The game is a endless runner and everything is working fine, but when I hit the Play button to actually start the game, the Player object automatically gives me one jump, after that, it's all normal, it's like when I hit Play button it hits the game and the player too at the same time. I need this working in a Android device.

Player.cs script

...

```
void Start () {
    Highscore = PlayerPrefs.GetInt ("Highscore", 0);
    jumpOne = false;
    jumpTwo = false;
    canDoubleJump = false;
}
void Update() {
    for (int i = 0; i < Input.touchCount; i++){
        if (Input.GetTouch(i).phase == TouchPhase.Began && isFalling == false) {
        jumpOne = true;
        canDoubleJump = true;
        isFalling = true;
        }else if (Input.GetTouch(i).phase == TouchPhase.Began && isFalling == true && canDoubleJump == true) {
        jumpTwo = true;
        canDoubleJump = false;
        }
    }
}

void FixedUpdate() {
    transform.Translate(Vector2.right * power * Time.deltaTime);
    if (jumpOne == true) {
        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(Vector2.up * jumpHeight);
        jumpOne = false;
    }
    if (jumpTwo == true) {
        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(Vector2.up * jumpHeight);
        jumpTwo = false;
    }
}

void OnCollisionStay2D(Collision2D coll) {
    if (coll.gameObject.tag == "Ground") {
        isFalling = false;
        canDoubleJump = false;
    }
}
```

...

//(Play Button)

```
public void ClickedStart() {
    MainMenu.SetActive(false);
    Time.timeScale = 1.0f;
    Playing = true;
}
```

Already tried and the problem still persists
(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))

(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)) Works fine and with no bugs, but I am not able to jump running in Android.

Answer (score 0):

You are using TouchPhase.Began so the moment u hide your main menu the touch is still active and hence the player jumps , I suggest you use a co-routine with waitforseconds method before you can start making the player jump again .

Comment: Lumb, beginners should never use a coroutine.  Just use simple `Invoke` call.

Comment: ok then try this if statement and put all your touch code inside it:  if(!MainMenu.isactiveSelf){} , see if that helps